# Oracle WITH clause restrictions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a quite complex query that is based on multiple tables unioned together. At the moment, we are using view in order to perform operations on all the rows we need, so the view and a query look like:

```
CREATE VIEW
    V_VIEW
    (
        COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
    ) AS
SELECT
    "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4"
FROM
    TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    "COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4"
FROM
    TABLE2;

SELECT
        COL1, COL2
FROM
    (   SELECT
            COL1, COL2
        FROM
            V_VIEW
        WHERE
            COL1 like 'val%'
        AND COL2 =
            (
                SELECT
                    MAX(COL3)
                FROM
                    V_VIEW
                WHERE
                    COL4 = 'Y' ) part1
UNION ALL
SELECT
        COL1, COL2
FROM
    (   SELECT
            COL1, COL2
        FROM
            V_VIEW
        WHERE
            COL1 like 'sth%'
        AND COL2 =
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(COL3)
                FROM
                    V_VIEW
                WHERE
                    COL4 = 'N' ) part2;
```

I'm looking for a way to improve performance of this query and unfortunately creating new table that consists all rows of Table1 and Table2 is not an option for now (we are not allowed to interfere with the way rows are being inserted there). I tried to use WITH clause instead of the view, so it would look a bit like:

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS (
SELECT
    COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
FROM
    TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
FROM
    TABLE2 )
SELECT
        COL1, COL2
FROM
    (   SELECT
            COL1, COL2
        FROM
            TEMP_TABLE
        WHERE
            COL1 like 'val%'
        AND COL2 =
            (
                SELECT
                    MAX(COL3)
                FROM
                    TEMP_TABLE
                WHERE
                    COL4 = 'Y' ) part1
UNION ALL
SELECT
        COL1, COL2
FROM
    (   SELECT
            COL1, COL2
        FROM
            TEMP_TABLE
        WHERE
            COL1 like 'sth%'
        AND COL2 =
            (
                SELECT
                    MIN(COL3)
                FROM
                    TEMP_TABLE
                WHERE
                    COL4 = 'N' ) part2
```

On a small data volume (Table1 and Table2 have about 20k rows) this improves performance very well. However, those tables will eventually get stuffed with millions of rows. I don't entirely understand how WITH clause is being processed, so I wonder: is there a chance that query using WITH closure, on a large set of data, will fail (due to lack of memory?), where a query without it would work slow, but will finish just fine?

Comment: Instead of `SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE COL2 = (SELECT MAX(COL3) FROM TEMP_TABLE)` you may use the [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following:

```
WITH main_res AS (SELECT col1,
                         col2,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN col4 = 'N' THEN col3) OVER () col3_n_max,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN col4 = 'Y' THEN col3) OVER () col3_y_max
                  FROM   v_view
                  WHERE  col1 LIKE 'val%'
                  OR     col1 LIKE 'sth%')
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   main_res
WHERE  (col1 LIKE 'val%' AND col2 = col3_y_max)
OR     (col1 LIKE 'sth%' AND col2 = col3_n_max);
```

This uses a conditional max analytic function to return the max value (depending on the col4 value) across all the rows.

Once you know that information, you can then filter on it appropriately. This should reduce the number of times you're querying each table, which usually is faster (but not always!) than the original query. I advise you test this query and work out if it's faster than the original query (and any other answers) before you choose which one to use.

Comment: . . This has one reference to the thing called "view", so I assume it is much faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it’s not always the case. Sometimes it can be faster to have the MAX in a separate subquery as the OP had originally, rather than using the analytic function (indexes may be used in the former that can’t in the latter, hence why I tell the OP to test themself !

Answer (score 1):

WITH clause is a kind of VIEW which is created on the fly, used and the code for wont get stored in the DB. However, the it consumes main memory to store the information related to the cursor which is used to retrieve rows from the WITH SELECT query. You are right; WITH query on tables with huge data will slow down the DB.

I am not aware of: 
a) Whether TABLE1 and TABLE2 hold full data set or these tables are incrementally updated.
b) Do we have date columns in this table?
c) At what interval these tables are populated or updated?

Based on the answers to above questions: 
After discussing with your DBAs:

1. You can ask DBAs to extract data belonging to TRUNC(SYSDATE) or TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 from TABLE1 and TABLE2 and populate this data into a single "new" table with same columns along with two additional columns:
   a) One column is going to contain 1st three letters of COL1 value. 
   b) Another column to hold status value with DEFAULT 'Q'.
2. Create a LIST partition on this new table on COL1 for values 'Val' and 'Sth' and COL4 for Y and N.
3. Write an anonymous block which prepares data the way you need. Then, simple query on this new table should fetch data for you. We can schedule this anonymous block in job schedule depending on the frequency at which data will be available in the source tables TABLE1 and TABLE2.

These suggestions are based on a set of assumptions and amount of information you have shared.

If there is any UI or report running on this data then, house keeping of this data is required.

Bottom line :

1. Prepare the data as required by the subsequent process(es) beforehand rather than preparing the data on-the-fly when it is required. This will simplify your entire process and query part also.
2. Most of the times when we encounter performance bottlenecks in Prod or Int environment, we always look for short-term solutions. Short-time solutions are very much required to sort out the issue at hand. However, I would suggest you to be prepared with a long-term solution as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice. About your questions: those tables contain some log data from the application. They are being constantly updated, new records are coming in and old are stored somewhere else and erased. Yes, I have one timestamp column there.

Comment: My pleasure. Oracle allows partition to create on DATE columns only; not on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE or WITH LOCAL TIMESTAMP. Application logs means I assume the data is populated (inserted) on daily or hourly basis. Compare the frequency/interval at which data is populated and the data is expected from your process. How many times an end user views this data in a day? For e.g. Suppose data is populated on hourly basis and end user expects/views data every four hour in a day or only once in day at the EOD or SOD next business day.

Comment: Yes, data is being populated live while users are taking particular actions within the application.

Comment: If you are going to follow an alternative like the one which I described above then, please ensure that these processes are in sync: Data loading interval, Data extraction by DBA, Data preparation before process picks it up and Time at which end user views the data.

Answer (score 0):

Before investing too much time in rewriting, it would be helpful to ensure that the optimizer is given a fighting chance at doing a good job. Make sure the tables have good stats and appropriate indexes.

Run explain plans on your queries to see what Oracle is actually doing in each case. You may find that something unexpected is going on with those UNION ALL statements. The optimizer sometimes makes dumb decisions and you may need to help it with indexes or strategically applied hints.

The WITH clause is quite handy and does the same job as a standalone view or a view defined inline in the table list, with one key exception: Oracle treats standalone views, WITH-clause views, and inline views slightly differently in the optimization process.
Oracle may choose to materialize the results of a view defined in a WITH clause, while it may merge the view if it is defined inline.

The point is that changing between these three kinds of views in your query will cause odd nuances of the optimizer to start showing up.

Finally, what version of Oracle are you on? The optimizer is one area where version really matters.

Comment: Thanks Tad. We are on 12c. I already did explanation plan analysis, compute statistics and put indexes into columns that are being used by a query. I'm looking for a further ways to improve that. That is why I'm wondering about restrictions of using WITH clause against big chunk of date as alternative to using a view.